# Structuring pagination for multiple data sources in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I hate to come here without some code but I'm stuck in the planning stage of a project I'm working on. I'm using Plaid to get transaction data from multiple accounts and need to return that info in chunks from an ExpressJS server. The biggest challenge I'm facing is how to handle the pagination when the data is coming from multiple sources. Since the response formats are the same (just coming from different accounts, thus different data) and they're timestamped, it shouldn't be hard to join the multiple data sources into one source where data can be extracted from. However that problem is paginating the data; since there'll be a lot of data coming in, I obviously want the option to return them bit by bit to the client, depending on the size value sent by the client. The most obvious solution to me is to store the combined data in my MongoDB, and then get data/paginate from there. Since I want the newest info, I would call the Plaid API each time to get the latest transactions but only update the DB if there's new info, perhaps by taking a hash or something of the responses and comparing them. Would this be the most reasonable solution? Or are there other, better options available that I'm not aware of? I apologize if this is a noob question, I'm still learning my way around backend engineering. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aggregating all of the data into your own MongoDB is a good choice.
You can use webhooks rather than constantly checking for new info on Plaid. https://plaid.com/docs/api/webhooks/#transaction-webhooks

Comment: @caffeinated.tech Thanks for the comment! Webhooks completely slipped my mind, but that sounds like the best solution if I am to aggregate the data in my DB. As for the DB itself, I'm probably expecting to have up to hundreds of thousands of transactions saved per user, but will that be an issue? I've never worked with huge data before so I'm not entirely sure on the limitations of MongoDB (using the cloud version), so just wanted to make sure.

Comment: The DB size depends on number of users and size of each document. I have 50M+ documents in multiple collections on M30 instances on Atlas, it's no problem. But at the size you describe, and as it's a banking software, I highly recommend some sort of DB design consultant. It's way easier to do it properly at the start than make migrations / fixes later when you have live clients. It's worth the investment. I can also recommend the MongoDB Atlas support for DB design questions

Comment: @caffeinated.tech Makes sense, thank you so much for the advice!